# Samba group write file permissions not set

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, file-sharing

On Ubuntu 16.04.1 (Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu), all shares ignore the `create mask` and `force create mode` for the group writable bit.

When creating a new text file on my home share, or on a global share, it's created with the permissions 0640, where I would have expected it to be 0660. The relevant portions of my `smb.conf` are below.

```
[global]
directory mask = 2770
create mask = 0660
map archive = no

[homes]
comment = Home Directory for %U
valid users = %S
read only = no
create mask = 0660
force create mode = 0660
directory mask = 2770
force directory mode = 2770
browseable = no

[build]
comment = Build Share
force user = %U
force group = buildshare
path = /mnt/build
read only = no
create mask = 0660
force create mode = 0660
directory mask = 2770
force directory mode = 2770
browseable = yes
```

If I change `create mask` to `0777` and `force create mode` to `0777` then the results are a little different and the permissions created are `755`, still the writable bits for group and other are not set when I would expect it to be with the `force create mode` option.

Setting `force create mode` in the `[global]` section doesn't change behaviour.

I'm not observing the same problem with using `directory mask` and `force directory mode` and I got that fixed after adding `force directory mode = 2770`

The Samba server is authenticating against an Active Directory Server (Win2012R2) for single sign on.

According to `smb.conf(5)`, it should work, and I'm baffled.

```
create mask (S)

       The default value of this parameter removes the group and other write and execute bits from the UNIX
       modes.

       Following this Samba will bit-wise 'OR' the UNIX mode created from this parameter with the value of
       the force create mode parameter which is set to 000 by default.
```

Comment: Still no luck. The commands `map {archive|hidden|system} = no` have no effect, neither does `unix extensions = no`. Setting `inherit acls = no` doesn't change anything either. Added security modes as here, doesn't work. http://askubuntu.com/questions/97669/i-cant-get-samba-to-set-proper-permissions-on-created-directories?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

The problem was "obey pam restrictions = yes" was set. Change this to "no" and the permissions are now set correctly. This was a comment in the post [Set umask, set permissions, and set ACL, but SAMBA isn't using those?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210808/set-umask-set-permissions-and-set-acl-but-samba-isnt-using-those)

Comment: You Sir, made my day! Thanks!