# Permission inconsistencies between OS's

Tags: permissions, samba

Trying to set up a Samba share where the members of the development group have full access to files in the share (regardless of the owner):

```
[global]
   workgroup = PREMPROVSOL
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.10.0/24
   bind interfaces only = yes
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   unix charset = UTF-8
   dos charset = CP932

[Development]
    path= /server/Development/
    writeable = yes
    create mask = 0777
    force create mode = 0777
    directory mask = 0777
    force directory mode = 0777
    security mask = 0777
    force security mode = 0777
    guest ok = no
    valid users = @development
```

Interestingly enough, the Windows 10 machine that accesses the share has more permissions than the Linux Mint machine logged in with the same credentials.  For example:

Windows 10:
Create Folder `FolderA` in the share then create folder `FolderA1` inside `FolderA`. No issues.

Linux Mint:
Create Folder `FolderA` in the share (Lock shows on folder). Unable to create anything inside `FolderA`

`fstab` entry on the Linux Mint box:

```
//10.0.10.240/Development /mnt/Development cifs nobrl,_netdev,vers=1.0,noserverino,iocharset=utf8,credentials=/home/spsimmons/.smbcred  0       0
```

Is there a setting somewhere I am missing?  Thanks!

***EDIT***

From the Win10 Machine, I create `FolderA` and it has the following permissions:

```
drwxrwsr-x+  3 1001 1004    0 Jul 10 12:39 FolderA
```

`FolderA1` inside of `FolderA` permissions:

```
drwxrwsr-x+  2 1001 1004    0 Jul 10 12:39 FolderA1
```

`1004` is the GID of the group.

Created a folder from the Win10 machine that the Linux machine cannot create in.
Created a folder from the Linux machine that the Win10 machine CAN create in.
I'm not using fuse but I did add the `file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777` parameters to my mount line.  Still no dice.

Comment: None of the listed operating systems are official Ubuntu so off topic. Plus please read up on permissions... Windows gets set during mounting

Comment: He is running an Ubuntu Samba server. It's designed to be accessed by Windows, MacOS, and other Linux systems. How is his post off topic?

Comment: Unless earthmeLon answered your question I would suggest you post in the Ubuntu Forum - in the Server section. The people marking this as "not about Ubuntu" appear to think this is not a networking question but perhaps a dual booting question? If earthmeLon did answer your question please mark it that way so others may benefit.

Comment: Dual Booting???  I never said anything about that.  I am running Ubuntu 19.04 as Samba Server.  Isn't this an "Ask Ubuntu" forum?  I have not marked earthmeLon's answer because it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Mount Windows Shares Permanently](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) has some great information and overview if you haven't seen it yet.  Very simply, I believe you need the `uid=` configuration option in your `/etc/fstab` mountpoint entry and `2777` [`umask`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) for directories.

---

Without you showing us the permissions of the directories (ie: `FolderA`, `FolderA1`) it will be hard to know for sure, but it is likely that the `umask` is set so that when files are created in Linux, they are created and associated to user's group and the user's user.

For example, if we have the shared directory `/srv/www/` owned by `www-data:www-data` and all of the files are `g+rw` and I am in the `www-data` group, I should be able to read and write to all of those files.  The complication occurs when I create a file as my user.  When that happens, the file is created as `user:user` and `www-data` isn't part of the `user` group (and shouldn't be).

So, when you create files you need to ensure that they are being created as and tied to the `developer` group.  The host system is both Windows and using a different filesystem type, so you have to consider that there is a translation layer (FUSE,SAMBA,CIFS) to adapt the files and permissions to work with Linux.

Normally, you'd be able to resolve these issues by setting up an entry in the Linux system's `/etc/fstab` and adding `uid=DEVELOPER_ID,gid=DEVELOPER_ID,umask=0777` for configuration options.  Instead of `umask` with many translated filesystems, we set the `file_mode` to determine the permissions of the files.  Directories will need to have an adjustment of the *special permission* from `0` to `2`.  This enforces the group ownership of new files and directories (ie: `2777`).  For example:

```
uid=userID,gid=userID,file_mode=2777
```

You can also [make this adjustment in your `smb.conf`](https://askubuntu.com/a/97752/13247) for directory-specific configuration values, but you should specify the `uid` and `gid` to be your user in your `fstab` entry to prevent other issues.

With our previous `/srv/www` example, we could make sure that newly created files were owned by `www-data` and `g+rwx` with the following commands:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /srv/www
sudo chmod g+rw /srv/www
sudo chattr +S /srv/www
```

Any newly created file in `/srv/www` should be owned by the `www-data` group and have `g+rw` permissions.